# Automatic click element after all data loaded in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am trying to figure out how to automatic trigger a click event on certain element after all data are loaded.

the code is like this in html file:

```
<div *ngFor="let location of locations; let i = index;" class="location-wrapper" (click)="onSelect($event, i); $event.stopPropagation();">
    <div class="location">{{ location }}</div>
</div>
```

the `onSelect()` method is doing some expansion of something that related to current location.

What I am trying to achieve is that I want the very first element of the `*ngFor` can be automatically clicked to show the things that related to it every time I get to this page.

Or maybe we can achieve it using other similar approach?

I have tried several ways to do this,
like putting some code in `window.on('load', function() { // blablabla });`

or using `ngAfterViewInit()` and `ngAfterViewChecked()`, both not work well.

Comment: You should use expand, collapse panel here to show more data. And make the first div as an active panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in at least 2 ways. The first one would be old-fashioned javascript `click()`. The second would be just using component logic, just create an variable like `selectedLocation` which would hold current `index` or `Object` that is currently expanded. Don't forget to add initial value to it to make it after load page visible.

#### Javascript dispatchEvent (not `Angular friendly solution`)

Simply we just need to grab our item and use `click()` function. That's it. To grab an element we can use basic javascript method document.getElementById(elementId)" or with `template variable`.

```
<div 
   [id]="'location_' + i" <!-- For biding with document.getElementById -->
   #locationPanel <!-- For biding with template variable -->  
   *ngFor="let location of locations; let i = index;" class="location-wrapper" (click)="onSelect($event, i); $event.stopPropagation();">
    <div class="location">{{ location }}</div>
</div>
```

With Id it would look like `document.getElementById("location_0").click()` this gonna dispatch click event on element.

For template variable in your component you need to add

```
@ViewChildren locationPanel: QueryList<any>;

openFirstLocation() {
   if (this.locationPanel && this.locationPanel.first) 
       this.locationPanel.first.nativeElement.click();
}
```

And in afterViewInit just call `this.openFirstLocation();`

Please note that it's not `Angular` friendly because `Angular` does not like when you interfere directly with `DOM`. However as long we don't change anything in structures then everything should be fine, but we should avoid manipulating dom with plain javascript.

Please note that too about using `@ViewChild` and `document.* methods`.

> Use this API as the last resort when direct access to DOM is needed. Use templating and data-binding provided by Angular instead. Alternatively you can take a look at Renderer2 which provides API that can safely be used even when direct access to native elements is not supported.
>   Relying on direct DOM access creates tight coupling between your application and rendering layers which will make it impossible to separate the two and deploy your application into a web worker.
>
> From `Angular docs` [link](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef)

Comment: I tried to add `#locationPanel`to the wrapper div, but when I try to `console.log(locationPanel.first)` in the `ngAfterViewInit()` it shows `undefined`. Strangely, when I only do `console.log(locationPanel)`, it has `first` property and its pointing to the right div that I want. Is this the problem lying in the order of DOM elements are loaded and the time of execution of `ngAfterViewInit()`